# command contains unrecognized phrase/keyword VFP with SQL

Tags: sql, syntax-error, visual-foxpro

im having a problem with a visual fox pro SQL command, it keeps giving me errors like "INNER JOIN doesnt exist" (when i put the inner join, and without it it says command contains unrecognized phrase/keyword when im doing the select

```
*!* SELECT * FROM ALTBREQU
*!* *--emp_ccodigo,req_cnumero,cen_ccodigo(codigo de centro de costo)
*!* SELECT * FROM ALTBDREQ
*!* *--emp_ccodigo, req_cnumero,pro_ccodigo,dre_ncantid,dre_ncosref
*!* SELECT * FROM ALTBPROD
*!* *--emp_ccodigo, pro_ccodigo, pro_cdescor
*!* SELECT * FROM COTBASOC
*!* *--emp_ccodigo,aso_ccodigo(unidad operativa),aso_cnombre
*!* SELECT * FROM CGTBCENT
*!* *--emp_ccodigo,cen_ccodigo,cen_cdescri

OPEN DATABASE dbalmacen
OPEN DATABASE dbcompras
OPEN DATABASE dbcontab

CREATE SQL VIEW prueba AS ;
SELECT * FROM ALTBREQU;
 JOIN ALTBDREQ ON ALTBREQU.req_cnumero = ALTBDREQ.req_cnumero AND;
JOIN ALTBPROD ON ALTBDREQ.pro_ccodigo = ALTBPROD.pro_ccodigo AND;
JOIN CGTBCENT ON ALTBREQU.cen_ccodigo = CGTBCENT.cen_ccodigo
```

Thanks you very much in advance.

Greetings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take out the `AND`s in the `JOIN` statements - that should let you use `INNER`:

```
CREATE SQL VIEW prueba AS ;
SELECT * FROM ALTBREQU;
INNER JOIN ALTBDREQ ON ALTBREQU.req_cnumero = ALTBDREQ.req_cnumero ;
INNER JOIN ALTBPROD ON ALTBDREQ.pro_ccodigo = ALTBPROD.pro_ccodigo ;
INNER JOIN CGTBCENT ON ALTBREQU.cen_ccodigo = CGTBCENT.cen_ccodigo
```

Comment: thanks you very much. it isnt showing me any results though, not even something empty

Comment: Well that statement just creates the view - it doesn't return any data.  Are you trying to use it in a subsequent statement?  What happens when you run the `SELECT` without creating a view?

Comment: deleted the view, and its working properly now, thank you very much for your help.